# What is AppMesh exactly offering?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-app-mesh

I've been researching App mesh , service discovery , load balancing , tracing and other concepts and basically running in a loop.
What is app mesh offering that cannot be achieved by combining other services ?

For example instead configuring app mesh to fetch from AWS cloud map , can't you just do it using the Amazon SDK in code and call X service ?

Also it's said it offers end to end visibility , but in what sense ? Since it's suggested to implement AWS x-ray with it , what more visibility is gained by app mesh that is not gained by implementing AWS x-ray independently?

We have an ECS cluster and what basically led me on this path is researching a way to log/trace HTTP requests and basically proper load balancing which can be achieved with a combination of route 53 and cloud map so why app mesh ?